# How to open Plan app with location from webpage link in iOS6?

Tags: html, ios6, maps, geocoding

On iOS <= 5, i only use:

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=48.853873,2.336883">See Paris on "Plan"</a>
```

and safari open the link in plan

On iOS6 this link is open in googlemaps website.
I see their is a "maps:" protocole but i don't know the syntaxe.

For example:

```
<a href="maps:48.853873,2.336883">See Paris on "Plan"</a>
```

will open "Plan" app on iOS6 but don't show any coordonate.

What is the minimal syntax for "maps:" protocole on iOS ?
Is their an API for "maps:" protocole for detailled syntax (adress, zoom level, ...) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I answer myself...

you can now use

```
<a href="http://maps.apple.com/maps?q=Paris,france">
```

on non iOS browser it will redirect to google maps.

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html

Comment: is there a way to open other app, like waze or google maps app?